# SignalR - RedisMessageBus excessive memory consumption

Tags: asp.net, .net, redis, signalr, dotmemory

I'm trying to use **Redis backplane** to scale-out **signalR** (**Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core 2.4.1**) at my app.

But as I can see there is a **big memory consumption (maybe leak)** by **RedisMessageBus**. 
During the day it is growing from 200 Mb to 1 Gb (about 5 hours)

I tried set **DefaultMessageBufferSize** to 100 (or less), but it looks like it doesn't help.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder builder)
        {
            GlobalHost.Configuration.DefaultMessageBufferSize = 100;
            ...
            builder.MapSignalR(SignalRServicePath, hubConfiguration);
        }
```

At that moment I'm run out of any ideas why this happens

### **Q:** Can you please help me resolve the issue or give insights into the route cause of such behavior ?

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Update**. After SignalR source code investigation I found out that actually **DefaultMessageBufferSize** only sets up initial default message buffer size, but doesn't limit it.

Thus, if there are a lot of input requests to server-side singlalR hub, the hub can't handle these requests and send out them to subscribers in time. I believe it's the root cause of memory consumption constant growing

**Q:** Is it possible to limit the maximum size of signalR messageStore (per connection, topic)?